# What is the purpose of 'flag' in a prime number program?

Tags: c++

I saw this code from a website and there wasn't any explanation behind or specifically the purpose of the flag line.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int n, i, m = 0, flag = 0;
  
  cout << "Input a number: ";
  cin >> n;
  
  m = n / 2;

  for(i = 2; i <= m; i++)
  {  
      if(n % i == 0)  
      {  
          cout << "Input is not a prime number." << endl;  
          flag = 1;
          break;  
      }  
  }  
  if (flag == 0) {
      cout << "Input is a prime number." << endl;
    }
    
  return 0;
}
```

P.S. It's a rookie question.

Comment: What do you think the code does? Did you try to explain it to yourself? Step by step? P.s. this is just some bad bad code. If you're a rookie don't look at it too much

Comment: Don't worry about its name.  Just focus on where and how its used.

Comment: Long time ago, in a galaxy nearby, before the `bool` type was standardized, people would use variables, often called flags, to indicate pass or failure.

Comment: Try removing it and see what happens.  You'll notice that in that case the program will tell you that 4 both isn't prime and that it is prime.

Comment: You could rename `flag` to `input_is_not_a_prime_number`, if that makes the code more readable.

Comment: _"there wasn't any explanation behind or specifically the purpose of the flag line."_  `flag` appears on _three_ lines.  Is one of those lines specifically more confusing than the others?

Comment: @Julian Williams The purpose of the flag is to make the program incorrect.:)

Comment: @Julian, if you have a new question, please ask a new question.  Do not change a question with answers so it is asking something different, invalidating the posted answers.

Comment: That code performs at least double the amount of checks that are necessary. Check for evenness once, than just try dividing by the odds. Those fixes alone cut the number of iterations in half. And I believe that's still a naive way to check for primes. At least it had the common sense to divide number being checked by 2.

Comment: This code could be improved in many ways.  The loop end, `m` only needs to be the square root of `n`, and `n / 2` is far too big, for most valid cases.  Also, if `break;` were changed to `return;` all uses of `flag` could be removed.

Comment: But good god, man! You're suggesting cleaner, more readable code that has TWO exits from the function. That extra exit will BREAK people's minds and cause mass confusion, resulting in the end of the world! Under no circumstances can we ever allow multiple exits from a function, no matter how much better the code would be! Or at least that's what I got out of the last coding standard I read that disallowed more than one exit from a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since that loop can exit for 2 reasons

- the number is not prime (there is a `break` statement)
- once i reaches m (the for loop terminates)

the code after the loop needs to know which exit happened so that it can say that the number is prime if it exited for the second reason. A more canonical way to do it is

```
 for(i = 2; i <= m; i++)
 {  
    if(n % i == 0)  
    {  
       cout << "Input is not a prime number." << endl;  
       break;  
    }  
 }  
 if (i > m) {
   cout << "Input is a prime number." << endl;
 }
```

ie look at the loop condition variables and see if the loop exit condition happened

of at least use a bool with a good name

```
bool not_prime = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

The "flag" variable is just a Boolean variable. If the number n is divisible by any number between 2 and n/2 then the program will display "Input is not a prime number" and flag will be set to 1 (then there's also the "break;" to end the cycle since you already proved the number is not prime). When the for ends then it checks if flag is equal to 0, if it is then it means the number is prime, else it won't display anything.